# Can I overload a Haskell function based on a Bool function call?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm not sure how to explain this very well so I'll just provide an example:

```
-- Create a list of ints if the string contains no numbers
row :: String -> [Maybe Int]
row (isAlpha row) = [ Just $ ord c | c <- row ]
row _ = [Nothing]
```

When I try to load a module with this in it in GHCi I get:

```
Parse error in pattern: isAlpha
```

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to do it all in an if..else?

**Ninja Edit:** This isn't a real example, obviously. I tried to extrapolate the behaviour I was after with a simple example but in hindsight this obviously makes no sense as isAlpha would return a Bool, not a String so it would be the wrong parameter and isAlpha works on Char not String's anyway. But I was just trying to portray the concept I was looking for, so I hope that's come through.

Comment: You want to use [pattern guards](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures). There is also the olde goode `if` expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are using `isAlpha` in a place where pattern matching (and pattern matching only) happens.
Use guards instead:

```
 row a | isAlpha a = someFunction
       | otherwise = someOtherFunction
```